# How do I access items in an OrderedDict within an OrderedDict?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I am querying Salesforce with simple_salesforce and getting the following as a result:

```
OrderedDict([('totalSize', 1),
             ('done', True),
             ('records',
              [OrderedDict([('attributes',
                             OrderedDict([('type', 'Contact'),
                                          ('url', '/services/data/v42.0/sobjects/Contact/0038')])),
                                          ('GUID', '7AFCC9D7'),
                                          ('Email', 'test@yahoo.com'),
                                          ('Contact_id', '0038')])])])
```

I want to access the last 5 entries (type, url, GUID, Email & Contact_id) and add them to a Pandas dataframe.

How would I go about accessing those entries?

Comment: With `d` your dictionary take a look at `pd.json_normalize(d, "records")`.

Answer (score 0):

In the specific example you provided you would access the first dictionary by `dict1['records'][-1]`. This works because `'records'` is a key in your main dictionary and its item is a list of ordered dictionaries. You want the last item of that list, so you index by `[-1]`.